# Is it possible that I could get who is speaking in FreeSwitch?

Tags: freeswitch

I have researched on the FreeSwitch official website.

I want to develop a task based on FreeSwitch, while I cannot find one API.

What I have already done is I let my program to dial a 4 digit number and set up a conference, then other clients could dial this 4 digit number to enter the conference. But I need another function, which is when a client is speaking, I want to get who is speaking.

I have researched a lot of the FreeSwitch official website and cannot find the answer. If I google "How to get who is speaking in FreeSwitch", and I cannot find something useful. Can any one please provide me some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use mod_esl to listen for events. one of the attributes is 'floor', and there are floor-change and video-floor-change events you can listen to.

[Start with an ESLConnection Object](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Event+Socket+Library)

bear in mind i'm terrible with freeswitch and feel your pain, so take what i say with a pinch of salt